# Get part of webpage with cURL

Tags: curl

So what I'm doing now is getting all the webpage that curl returns from the request I make. What I'm looking for is to make curl download only a part from that page in order to speed things up a bit, something like from character n to character m of the webpage. Is there any way to do this? Maybe not with curl?
Thanks.
Edit: So if the server doesn't support a range request, can I get only from the first character until some n character and stop downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with a HTTP range request - if the server allows it. curl supports that with the `-r` or [--range](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-r) option. Like if you want byte index 15 to and including byte index 29 from a URL:

```
curl -r 15-29 http://example.com
```

If the server doesn't support byte ranges (common when the server generates the response dynamically), an easy approach is to just pipe the output to `head` and have that stop at the suitable point:

```
curl -s http://example.com | head --bytes=100 > output
```

Comment: Sorry, annoying you again, if I'm making curl save the cookies to a file, won't that be a problem if it gets stopped like that?

Comment: No, the cookies are already received (as part of the response headers) when it gets stopped and it will save the cookies even when stopped like this.